# Is Noetherian or Artinian property a property of certain abelian category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Consider any abelian category $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose I have three objects $A,B,C\in Obj(\mathcal{C})$ forming an exact sequence in $\mathcal{C}$ as $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$.

Suppose $A,C$ has noetherian/artinian property(i.e taking subobjects of $\mathcal{C}$ forming a sequence and this sequence stabilizes.) It seems given subobjects of $A',C'$ of $A,C$ respectively, I can construct $B'$'s subobject as $A'\oplus C'$ which exists in abelian category. However my gut tells me that I do not know how to send the element of $A'\oplus C'$ to $B$.

Q1. Does $B$ must have artinian/noetherian property or is above statement correct?

Q2. Can I use the noetherian/artinian property of module category to other abelian category as above described?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Jeremy Rickard helpfully  points out in the comments, my answer below is not quite correct and one cannot use the Mitchell Embedding Theorem but can adapt the usual proof (essentially using the universal properties of coproducts, kernels and cokernels) to work in an abelian category without mentioning any elements.

You can use the [Mitchell embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem) to pretend that your abelian category is just a subcategory of modules over some ring. But here [the usual proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173284/a-question-about-a-proof-of-noetherian-modules-and-exact-sequences) shows that the middle object of an exact sequence is Noetherian (Artinian) if and only if the left and right objects are. So it must be true in your abelian category too.

Comment: I think the usual proof that you link to can be adapted in a straightforward way to work in an arbitrary abelian category. But I don't think using the Mitchell embedding theorem works. The problem is that the embedding into a module category may not preserve the lattice of subobjects of an object, and so may not preserve the property of being Noetherian or Artinian.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thank you. This makes sense. I've fixed my answer.