# artinian case unclear

Tags: ring-theory

Proposition 4.64 from Introduction to Homological Algebra by Rotman states:

Let R have either chain conditions on left ideals. If f: P $\to$ B and g: Q $\to$ B are projective covers of a finitely generated left R-module B, then Q and P are isomorphic.

In the proof, it is stated that ' Since R has either chain condition on left ideals, P being finitely generated forces P to have either chain condition on submodules.'

I can see it in the case of being noetherian as P finitely generated plus R left noetherian gives every submodule of P is f.g., hence P is left noetherian. However, I don't follow in the artinian case since there seems no analogous properties. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If $R$ is left Artinian, it is left Noetherian, by Hopkins' theorem.

Comment: That's right. But the converse is false. So when we get P is noetherian, it is not necessarily artinian, hence it doesn't necessarily have DCC, is it correct? I might be being silly here. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the following result: if $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ is a short exact sequence, then $M$ is Artinian if and only if $L$ and $N$ are Artinian.  An immediate consequence is that a finite direct sum of Artinian modules is Artinian.  The same results hold for Noetherian in place of Artinian.

If $M$ is a finitely generated module over an Artinian ring $R$, then $M$ is a quotient of $R^d$ for some $d$.  By the above, $R^d$ is Artinian and thus $M$ is Artinian.

You can find the result about short exact sequences in any number of references (though not Rotman, apparently): for example, it's Proposition 6.3 in "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah and MacDonald.  You can also find it on this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173284/a-question-about-a-proof-of-noetherian-modules-and-exact-sequences).

Comment: thank you so much for the enlightenment, Allen! Sorry for a silly question. Why If M is f.g, then M is a quotient? Would you please shed some light on this？thank you!